# Solving $y'' + 2y' +5y = 8\sinh x$ using variation of parameters

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We were asked to solve the following o.d.e using the method of variation of parameters.
$$y'' + 2y' + 5y = 8 \sinh x$$
It's fairly easy to solve using the method of undetermined constants and I got:

$$ y(x) = e^{-x} (A\cos 2x+B\sin 2x)-e^{-x}+ \frac{e^{x}}{2}$$

But it's a real mess to do this using the variation of parameters here's my try:
$$ y_h(x) =C_1e^{(-1+2i)x}+C_2e^{(-1+2i)x} $$
$$ y_1(x) = e^{(-1+2i)x}$$
$$ y_2(x) = e^{(-1-2i)x}$$
and
$$y_p(x)=\lambda(x)y_1(x)+\mu(x)y_2(x)$$
Wronskian matrix:
$$ W = -4ie^{-2x}$$

with this I get:
$$ \lambda(x)= \int{\frac{(e^{x}-e^{-x}).y_2}{-ie^{-2x}}dx}$$
$$ \mu(x)= \int{\frac{(e^{x}-e^{-x}).y_1}{-ie^{-2x}}dx}$$

Then I am pretty much stuck from here on because the answer i get doesn't resemble the one i got from the method of undetermined constants.
Any help/tips will be really appreciated.

Comment: since you are solving for real $y$, you take the real part of the $y_i's$ you have found which will make the integration simpler. After that, the integration you have to deal with is purely in terms of exponentials, which have the simplest anti-derivatives as you should know.

Comment: How comes you have $e^x+e^{-x}$ in the integral it should be $e^x-e^{-x}$ since the inhomogeneous part of the DE is a sinh function not a cosh function

Comment: @dezdichado There's a problem with the idea of taking only the real part because i'll get $y_1 = y_2 = \frac{\cos 2x}{e}$. It won't be purely in terms of exponential but will result in product of exponential function and secant after i multiply one of the functions with x to make it independent. It again leads away from what is correct.

Comment: @Aryadeva thanks i corrected it.